# Сайт для абсолютного позиционирования

Tags: python, tkinter, позиционирование, разметка, координаты

Есть ли сайт на котором можно мышкой поставить место объекта в окне, и получить его координаты для абсолютного позиционирования? Нужно для метода `place` в Tkinter, чтобы не подбирать координаты

Comment: При чем тут сайт? Как я понимаю, вам просто нужно отловить событие мыши на окне, из объекта события получить координаты, и по этим координатам установить виджет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовать можно через pyautogui, на мой взгляд проще

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.mouseInfo()
```